# Is it possible to check if a UITableViewCell is editable?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I set the editable boolean flag with this method

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
// Return YES if you want the specified item to be editable.
    if (indexPath.row<[requiredFields count]) {
        if ([[requiredFields objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"Required"]) {
        return NO;
        }
    }
    return YES;
}
```

So that means some cells are editable and some not. But when I click continue and I want to check the cells that are Not Editable to be Not Empty. So in a loop i get the cell like this

```
ShtoFushaTableViewCell * tempCell =  [shtoFushaTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:i inSection:0]];
```

now with this `tempCell` how can i check if it is editable or not ?

Comment: not edit mode, "Editable" if it can be deleted or not

Comment: You can create a NSDictionary or something to save editable state of your tableviewcells by IndexPath.

Comment: That won't work because if there are 3 cells and the middle one is deletable and i delete it, cell 3 becomes 2 but on the NSDictionary cell 2 is deletable and its wrong.

Comment: With those kinds of operation, you must first update your data source, then perform the UI delete operation. So in your case, you need to first delete the entry at the same array index in requiredFields array, then, go [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPath:@[indexPath]]; thing.

Comment: You have to update your dictionary when you change Cells (insert, delete, update deletable state) of your TableView. It should work.

Comment: @tyt_g207 ye thats what I did in the end thanks. An isEditable attribute would have been nice from those lazy apple people.